# Should we have Alibaba Cloud specific tags?

Tags: discussion

The past few weeks I've seen questions specifically about [Alibaba Cloud](https://www.alibabacloud.com/product/apsaradb-for-rds?spm=a3c0i.7911826.675768.dnavproductsd1.66c31103GqDNvh) databases (AsparaDB can function as MySQL, SQL Server, or Postgres) both for the first time and seemingly in waves. I'm not sure if some resource is pointing users to the DBA SE site or if there has been an uptick in Alibaba Cloud DB users.

Most of the questions have been below our standards / irrelevant, and so are now gone, but that doesn't mean the topic of AsparaDB questions isn't valid overall and I suspect the frequency of questions on the topic may increase. The tag `amazon-rds` has 435 uses and `aws` has 232 uses.

Should we have `alibaba-rds` and/or `asparadb` tags?

Comment: +1 for ApsaraDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I suspect the frequency of questions on the topic may increase.

If and when it does, suitable tags will naturally be added by users with the [create tags privilege](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Until then, I see no sensible reason (or method) to add tags for (non-spam) questions we don't have yet.